# How to add multiple pages with React & Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm coding a MediumBlog like application and I'm using React & redux and Django Rest Framework for my Backend. I already made the first page, which is the first page you see when you go to https://medium.com/ 
I'm able to navigate to different categories without refreshing the page, which is the Main Purpose of React. But now, when you want to read a post in the medium blog, the page is refreshing. I have no idea how to do it with react. I know how to build a Single Page App, but here, it seems that a new page is being loaded when you click on a post. My question is :

.Is this loading a new page instead of a new route ( a new HTML file or something ) 
.How can I handle this " multipage " structure with react

Here is my Single Page App that can load content from different categories

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './css/App.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '../store.js';
import AppHeader from './header/AppHeader';
import HeaderCategories from './header/HeaderCategories'
import PostListStream from './posts/PostListStream';
import PostList from './posts/PostList';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div className="App">
          <AppHeader />
          <HeaderCategories />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact
                   key="sciences"
                   path="/sciences"
                   render={() => <PostListStream field="sciences" />}
            />
            <Route exact
                   key="littérature"
                   path="/littérature"
                   render={() => <PostListStream field="littérature" />}
            />
            <Route exact
                   key="sciences-sociales"
                   path="/sciences-sociales"
                   render={() => <PostListStream field="sciences-sociales" />}
            />
          </Switch>
          <PostList />
        </div>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter>
                  <App />
                </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here is where my  are :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './css/App.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '../store.js';
import AppHeader from './header/AppHeader';
import HeaderCategories from './header/HeaderCategories'
import PostListStream from './posts/PostListStream';
import PostList from './posts/PostList';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div className="App">
          <AppHeader />
          <HeaderCategories />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact
                   key="sciences"
                   path="/sciences"
                   render={() => <PostListStream field="sciences" />}
            />
            <Route exact
                   key="littérature"
                   path="/littérature"
                   render={() => <PostListStream field="littérature" />}
            />
            <Route exact
                   key="sciences-sociales"
                   path="/sciences-sociales"
                   render={() => <PostListStream field="sciences-sociales" />}
            />
          </Switch>
          <PostList />
        </div>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter>
                  <App />
                </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Take a look at the `react-router-dom` library which should tell you all about SPA routing.

Comment: Hello @ChristopherNgo. Isn't react-router only working with single page application ? I'm asking because I have no idea if it is true. I don't know how to load a complete new page with react router. I hope that it is clear haha

Comment: @Valentin can you post your code so we can guide you to achieve this. i hope you have configured `react-router-dom` in your project.

Comment: @TRomesh I'm updating my post. Thank you

Comment: I added the files where I'm using React-Router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dynamic routes to your posts using `react-router-dom` in a similar way to what you have done with your other routes. `react-router` doesn't really refresh the page, although it looks like it. It simply renders another component when the `route` changes.

To create dynamic routes for your posts you can do something like this:

```
<Route
  path="/post/:postId"
  render={() => <PostComponent />}
/>
```

or like this if you want it to be a little more readable:

```
<Route
  path="/post/:postId"
  component={PostComponent}
/>
```

`:postId` here is a dynamic id, whatever is placed after `/post/` in your URL will be considered the `postId` by `react-router`.

Inside your `PostComponent` you can do something like this to fetch your `postId` variable:

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom"; 

const PostComponent = withRouter(props => (
  const postId = props.match.params.postId;

  return ();
))
```

You can then use your `postId` to fetch your post from the backend and do whatever you need to do with it. As soon as you go to your post URL now, it will show the `PostComponent` without hard refreshing the page.

Comment: Thank you so much ! So i have to do the exact same thing but this Time i have to load an Article component instead of a poststream component ?

Comment: Yes that's right, and then inside your `Article` component you can fetch your post from the backend using your `postId` and render it.